# solve $x^3-2x^2-x+1 = 0 \pmod{7^3}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to solve the equation $x^3-2x^2-x+1 = 0 \pmod {7^3} $ .                                    I tried first to find a solution $\mod 7$ , I got that $3$ is a solution , denote $x =$ $3+7t $ . now find a solution $\mod 7^2 $ , I got that for $t= 37 $ , there is a solution , thus $x =$ $3+7\times37 \pmod {49} $ $=$ $ 17 \pmod {49} $ .                 Now in the same way , denote $x =$ $17 +49t$, solve for $ 7^3 $, now here I got that there is no solutions and I can't decide if there is no solution or that I did something wrong. Is there a solution for this equation ?

Comment: You should check the derivative if you want to use Hensel’s lifting.  This is the issue in this example.

Comment: If the solution lifts, the $t$ only needs to be between $0$ and $7$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = 3 + y$, then $P(x) = y^3 + 7 y^2 + 14 y + 7$. Hence $7$ divides $y$, hence $49$ divides $7$ which is false. There is no solution.